# Express JS - Viewing/Inspecting the Response Object?

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm using Express version 4.13.4.

I would like to view and inspect the `res` object. If I `console.log()` it, it's too big to see properly in a command window.

I've tried using [`jsonfile`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonfile) to save it to a `.json` file but because it seems to be self referencing, I get:

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Does anyone know the parts of the `res` object that are circular..? I could make a copy of the object and then remove the those bits, so I can view the rest of the object.

```
let resCopy = res;
resCopy.circularProp = null;
// save to a file
```

It's possible I'm not understanding a `circular structure` correctly, feel free to put me straight.

What's the best way to inspect the `res` object..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The util.inspect() (built-in node.js library) function can convert a JavaScript object with functions / circular structures without failing on them, e.g.:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var util = require("util");
var resAsString = util.inspect(res);
fs.writeFileSync("inspect-res.json", resAsString, "utf8");
```

this code will convert the res object to a JSON-like string and write it to the inspect-res.json file in a formatted view.

Circular structure means that there are objects that contains references to themselves so there is infinite depth, e.g. res.obj1.obj2.obj1.obj2.obj1.obj2...